# Logging all occurences of a specifc pattern in separate files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file containing the following data:

```
"ItemList":  
  "Resource" : "6"  
  "ResourceIdentifier" : "12345"  
  "ResourceEventTime" : "2015-01-20T10:51:39Z"  
  "ResourceIdentifier" : "12345"  
  "ResourcePosition" : "2"  
  "Resource" : "7"  
  "ResourceIdentifier" : "12345"  
  "ResourceEventTime" : "2014-01-20T10:51:39Z"  
  "ResourceIdentifier" : "12345"  
  "ResourcePosition" : "17"
```

Is it possible to retrieve all patterns starting with "Resource" till "ResourcePosition" in separate files like-

File1

```
"Resource" : "6"  
"ResourceIdentifier" : "12345"  
"ResourceEventTime" : "2015-01-20T10:51:39Z"  
"ResourceIdentifier" : "12345"  
"ResourcePosition" : "2"
```

File2

```
"Resource" : "7"  
"ResourceIdentifier" : "12345"  
"ResourceEventTime" : "2014-01-20T10:51:39Z"  
"ResourceIdentifier" : "12345"  
"ResourcePosition" : "17"
```

I tried using

```
cat FormattedJsonStructure | grep -m 1 -A 5 Resource
```

with this I got 1st pattern. To get next pattern I tried

```
cat FormattedJsonStructure | grep -m 2 -A 5 Resource
```

but it gave me both continuous pattern.

Comment: Describe you problem clearly and what all the things you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` command could be used to make separate files:

```
grep FormattedJsonStructure --no-group-separator -A 4 -e "Resource" > AllResource
split -l 5 AllResource Resource
```

Note that `-A 4` alltogether with the matched line means 5 lines.